# create pandas column with new values based on values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

dataframe a:

```
    id    value
-------------------------------
0   231   9243
1   392   81139
2   493   896546
3   879   31
```

dataframe b:

```
   id   description  colour
-------------------------------
0  231  football     brown
1  392  bat          white
2  556  chicken      yellow 
3  493  tennis ball  yellow
4  119  pig          pink
5  879  cricket ball red
```

My question is how can I create a new column in dataframe a that inputs the description from dataframe b based on matching to the id column values in dataframe a? So I end up with:

```
    id    description    value    
-------------------------------
0   231   football        9243
1   392   bat             81139
2   493   tennis ball     896546
3   879   cricket ball    31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dict for mapping `id` and `description` from dataframe `b` and then use `.map()` on dataframe `a` on `id` columns, as follows:

```
b_dict = dict(zip(b['id'], b['description']))
a['description'] = a['id'].map(b_dict).fillna('')
```

Result:

```
print(a)

    id   value   description
0  231    9243      football
1  392   81139           bat
2  493  896546   tennis ball
3  879      31  cricket ball
```

Answer (score 1):

via `left merge`

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2[['id','description']], on='id', how='left')
```

**output**

```
    id   value   description
0  231    9243      football
1  392   81139           bat
2  493  896546   tennis_ball
3  879      31  cricket_ball
```